# My contract is failing to deploy because my code is not reading what address I am deploying from. How can I get this contract to deploy?

Tags: solidity, ganache, python, brownie, ganache-cli

```
    from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage

def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = accounts[0]
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from: account"})
    print(simple_storage)

def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()
```

My terminal returns `AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a "from" field specifying the address to deploy from`

I do not understand what is going on here because if I add `print(account)` it will print the public key that I am using. However, it is telling me that it does not know what address that I am deploying from. To me it is clearly specified, but the code says otherwise. This is what Patrick Collins did in his Solidity course, and it will not work for me. I am under the assumption that an update in Brownie changed the format of this. I need some help, and it would greatly appreciated if someone could specify some new syntax to use when deploying from an account on a local blockchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your deploy_simple_storage function you mistakenly put account variable in "".

Try this:

```
def deploy_simple_storage():
    account = accounts[0]
    simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    print(simple_storage)
```

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense. I assumed that the error had to something with the syntax or how I was formatting my code.